# Replacing some "\n" doesn't works

Tags: javascript, replace

I have a text like this:

> Sheldons Mutter Mary ist zu Besuch. Doch die Freude währt nicht lange: Statt von seiner Mutter ein Brathähnchen zubereitet zu bekommen, geht sie lieber auf Leonards Vorschlag ein, Sushi essen zu gehen. Sheldon hat zudem ein Unterhaltungsprogramm für Mary ausgearbeitet. Er muss aber schockiert zur Kenntnis nehmen, dass seine Mutter den Besuch eines Vortrags mit einem Nobelpreisträger ablehnt und stattdessen lieber mit den anderen eine Stadtrundfahrt macht.\n\nLeonard und Sheldon sind brillante Physiker, die meist in ihrem Apartment abhängen und ihre Videogames pflegen. Nur ihre Nachbarin Penny schafft es hin und wieder, für Abwechslung zu sorgen.

Now I want to replace `\n\n` with a `<br />`. So when I execute the line below, it doesn't do anything.

```
replace(/(\r\|\n|\r)/gm, "<br />");
```

However, it does work in the console.

Comment: Your plaintext has no newlines ..

Comment: @FritsvanCampen it _does_ have `\n\n`

Comment: the problem is your text does not have newlines, it has \n, that is `"\\n"` in Javascript. But \n in regex means newline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you seem to want to replace `\n\n` in a text like: `foo\n\nbar` - which to me sounds very strange by the way - you could do with this regexp:

```
var plain = "foo\\n\\nbar";
console.log(plain.replace(/\\n\\n/gm, "<br />"));
```

Comment: well done :) thanks, yeah I know that's sounds strange but I get this from a json file and I have to replace it. But good work :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
var r = new RegExp("\n\n" , "g");
str = str.replace(r, "<br />");
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bmMQN/4/

Comment: @Cherniv that shows that it doesn't work, your plaintext has `\n` not `\\n`.

Comment: This is going to look for the backslash character followed by the `r` character, followed by the `|` character, followed by another backslash character, and so on.

Comment: Cherniv: It works in your jsFiddle because you're using `\n` in the string, which translates to a new line, whereas the actual string has literal characters. So in the fiddle, to represent the problem string, you'd need to do `\\n\\n`, then in the regexp, you'd need `new RegExp("\\\\n\\\\n")`, or just `/\\n\\n/`

Comment: good job :) finally you have found a solution :) thanks for your effort

Comment: @MichaelUnterthurner i knew it! ;) Patience is the power!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is missing 1 `n`

```
replace(/(\r\|\n|\r)/gm, "<br />");
```

should be

```
replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "<br />");
```

As it is now, it matches "\r|\n" OR "\r"

However, judging from the comments it indeed seems that your text does not have newlines but backslash characters and letters n (`\n`).

Thus the proper regex for them is

```
/(\\r\\n|\\n|\\r)/gm
```

Answer (score 0):

The line below will replace newlines with `<br />` tags.

```
replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />');
```